# Is there a "Gaussian Transform"?

Tags: linear-algebra

A Fourier transform takes a signal and decomposes it according to
$$\hat{f} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) \exp(-2i\pi\nu t)dt.$$

From a linear algebra point of view, each pair of frequency function $\exp(2i\pi \nu_{i,j} t)$ is independent for $i\neq j$ thus acting like a orthogonal base.

The same can be considered by writing a function in terms of a sum of delta Dirac functions as

$$f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) \delta(y-t) dy.$$

We can also consider that this is a decomposition in some vectors that are orthogonal.

$\textbf{Is there something similar for Gaussians? }$

My first way of answering this at least by intuition is as follows. Consider the heat equation. It can be solved for an initial condition given by the Dirac delta function. Then one simply has to add that solution for each point of the domain (the procedure from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions)). Each solution for the Dirac Delta function becomes a gaussian after some time $t>0$ so I can think that the solution is written as a sum of gaussians. Going further, those gaussians seem to form a basis, not necessarily orthogonal, but a basis nevertheless.

So there are some instances where functions are written as in terms of Gaussians, but I did not manage to find something like a transform that does this decomposition say for all the gaussians of some fixed width but with different mean.

I did not try any calculation in order to identify some base vectors so far, but I want to try this after I assure myself that it has not been already done and generalized by others.

Comment: Possibly related: [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform)